# Symfony with docker, trouble editing

Tags: symfony, docker

I wanted to use Docker to create a local server for my Symfony3 app at work. Truth is, I've never used Docker before.

I saw some tutorials about Docker, then used this repo https://github.com/anacicconi/dockerized-symfony to start somewhere, and I created a new project with `symfony new` command to be sure there's no error in the code.

When I go through my container with `docker exec`, the files of my project are modified exactly like they are in local (if I replace `welcome` in my twig template by `potato`, and then do a `cat` on the file from my container, it'll reflect the changes).

But, when I go to `localhost:8000`with my browser, or if I display it with `curl` in my console, it is still the old Symfony index page.

I tried to simply remove the template file, and as expected, it created an error, though it didn't display a Symfony-like error, but a normal client-side error (error 500).

I also tried to create a route, and link it to a new template file, but this gives me a 404 error (once again, not with all explanations I usually get from Symfony).

I tried to recreate the container several times, delete the cache folders, tried on Chrome and Firefox, change some configuration files... But I'm out of ideas now.

---

(edit) Some colleagues helped me to solve the Symfony errors problem, and they told me that since we're going to build an API, views do not matter. I'm still curious to know the answer, but it is not as important as it was one hour ago.

(edit2) It seems that the problem disappears when I use the link `localhost:8000/app_dev.php`. It's enough for me.

Comment: My hello just disappeared from the message. So hello from here o/

Comment: If you `curl localhost:8000` *inside* the container, does it show the changes as well?

Comment: it fails to connect (`curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused`)

Comment: Welcome Elwin. You will see some Hello / Thanks are discouraged. Don't take it personally, you can see why there: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: Do you see the symfony profiler on your page?

Comment: I don't (seems I'm not in dev mode)

Comment: You are connecting from outside of the symphony system and remote debugging is disabled. This is the reason you don't see any error details. I am looking at the repository you specified in question, and I want to know what changes you made before running container.

Comment: I just had some help from some colleagues, and we manage to get the Symfony errors back. They told me that we won't use views anyway, so I don't have to worry about that since the controller system works perfectly (returning a json works as intended).

I'm still curious to know _why_ the view wouldn't actualize...

And I didn't make any changes except the .env filed provided by the repo (I filled all the missing values with my own).

Comment: Looks like you're using `prod` env, which has cached views. What about `localhost:8000/app_dev.php`?

Comment: Ok, it does work with `localhost:8000/app_dev.php`. Why wouldn't it with the prod env?

Comment: Try log with ssh to you container and run php "app/console(or bin/console for symfony 3+) cache:clear --env=prod"

Comment: I changed my Docker stack, so now I have several containers, and I'm struggling with the connection between Symfony and MySQL, so this command gives me a `connection refused` error. I'm fixing this and I'll see what happen next.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're missing port forwarding when running container:

```
docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:22:22 -p 127.0.0.1:8000:8000 you_contaner_image_name
```

Port 22 to connect to machine via ssh

Comment: I used the shell script provided with the repo to launch my container... I tried to save the container as an image with `docker commit` and launch your command but it stops immediately.

Comment: You need to do it only first time you creating container. Next time you will only use "docker ps -l" (to get container name) and "docker start container_name", and that's all. I'm not sure if it's possible to add port forwarding when container is running